# Using fixed strings in regular expressions?

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, csv, csv-simple

I am writing a bash script which accepts a list of CSV files as arguments and outputs e-mail addresses only found in the first file.  To accomplish this, for each record in the first CSV file I look up the e-mail address field and read its contents into a shell variable.  Then, I use `grep -iE` with the following regular expression to look up the e-mail address just found in all the remaining files, making sure that it is not a substring (e.g. *he@a.com* is not the same as *she@a.com*), and allowing it to be at the beginning or end of a record:

```
"^(.*,)?($EMAIL_ADDRESS|\"$EMAIL_ADDRESS\")(,.*)?\$"
```

A problem with this approach is that e-mail addresses contain dots which have a special meaning in regular expressions.  My questions are:

1. How can I avoid this problem in an elegant way?
2. How can I avoid this problem in a more general context, e.g. when the value to look up is not an e-mail address but some free text and might contain other special characters as well?

Comment: Use Perl instead of bash: [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta).

Comment: `awk -F, '$2 == "he@a.com"'`?

Comment: use a backslash `\.` in front of the dot to escape it.  you probably need **two** backslashes `\\.` to get the shell to pass **one** to the program.

Comment: You can use `grep -F` to do not treat pattern as regular expression, just like a string and `-w` option (whole word) which mean that pattern should fill full "word" ( so " `he@`" is not compare " s`he@`")

Answer (score 1):

in perl regexp (`grep -P ...`) you may use `\Q...\E` to protect meta chars

```
grep -P "(^|,)\Q$EMAIL\E(,|$)" file.csv
```

where:

- `(^|,)`   = start of field
- `(,|$)`   = end of field

Comment: Don't you need to escape the `$`? Also, where are `\Q` and `\E` documented?

Comment: In bash both `...$)` and `...\$)` work. Escaping is shell dependent. `\Q...\E` is document in any tutorial about perl-like regexp. See also the "quotemeta" link of @choroba comment.

Comment: This can fail if the variable `$EMAIL` contains a literal `\E`. Here's an example: `x='\E^a'; printf %s\\n "$x" a  | grep -P "\Q$x\E"`. Grep doesn't match the value `$x` but matches the string `a` which is different from `$x`.